# Laravel 5.2 Jwt user not found

Tags: php, laravel

I've setup JwtAuth in Laravel 5.2. When I use the `jwt.auth` middleware like this:

```
  $api->group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function($api)
    {
        $controllerPath = 'App\Http\Controllers\api\v1\\';

        $api->resource('user', 'App\Http\Controllers\api\v1\userController');
        $api->post('/authuser','App\Http\Controllers\api\v1\userController@authUser');
    });
```

The user is found and I receive his/her information.

But when I use the `jwt.refresh` middleware I receive the error that the user is not found:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

How is this possible, I've this problem for quit some time now. Could someone please give me a solution?

Comment: which library are you using? if possible link to library in github

Comment: @murlidharFichadia I use this libary: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Comment: I guess you need to update your library. Wbat version it is. Many have struggled with the same problem. Make sure you have latest php verdion and composer update which will remove and reinstall the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a manual fix. In jwt.php file just set the blacklist functionality to false. And it should work fine.

You are facing this issue i guess.

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/83

Author has updated the package to get rid of the error. As the problem is that the new token too gets blacklisted on refresh.

Comment: The problem is not that the token isn't valid but the user isn't find anymore if I do return Auth::user();

Comment: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/155 check here. Its to do with the primary key i guess. Can you set primarykey. As shown in the link

Comment: thanks! I had to use JWTAuth::toUser(JWTAuth::getToken());